# How to make ConEmu execute .sh in the same window with Git for Windows?

Tags: windows, git, conemu, sh

I'm using ConEmu on Windows with Git for Windows installed. When I try to execute an .sh script, the software starts an instance of Windows' default console and executes the script there. How can I make ConEmu / Git for Windows execute the .sh script in the same window the command is initialized from?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/36215512/1405560

Comment: You also posted this on [so]. Please do **not** crosspost. See [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068)